# Tesla Coil Troubleshooting Help!

Tags: troubleshooting, tesla-coil

A couple weeks ago I decided to build a tesla coil and after a decent amount of research and building time the coil could only light up a light bulb. I have tried many things to fix it but all to no avail. Some issues I think it might have is too small of a capacitor and not enough windings on the primary coil. I made leyden jar capacitors and a bucket capacitor, which had a total capacitance of 20 nanofarads (which seems awfully small compared to all the tutorials I followed). Additionally, I only had enough copper tubing to make the primary 6 turns. Anyways, here are some of the coils details:700 secondary turns, two microwave oven transformers in series, toroid is 15" by 4", and a static spark gap.
If anyone could help me with the problems I would be very appreciative. Thank you guys!

Edit: Accordingly, my question was unclear so bear with me because I am new to this community. I am asking how to optimize the power output of my Tesla coil because it currently cannot produce actual sparks. I described the set-up to the best of my ability but if there are any other specs that would actually change the performance than please let me know so i can give those as well. I hope that this feed can help others that are new to Tesla coil design as well because I feel that the optimization and tuning is a common mistake beginners make. Anyways after adding 6 more turns to the primary and testing 5 points per turn the sparks still have not been made. Perhaps this is because of the 4400 volts from the MOTs rather over 10,000 volts that some NSTs can supply.

Comment: A "jar" in early units (from a 1928 book I have) was 1.1 nF so 20nF isn't awfully small.

Comment: How are you limiting the MOT current?

Comment: Sorry, but a "microwave oven transformer" is not an accepted unit of inductance.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Why do you feel you need to know the inductance of the high voltage transformer(s)?

Answer (score 1):

In order for a Tesla coil to work with any sort of efficiency you really can't just throw it together. It requires math, tuning, and most of all, patience. The secondary circuit (Secondary coil and topload) must resonate at the same frequency as the primary circuit (primary coil and tank capacitor). Resonant frequency is calculated by:

[image]

where f is the resonant frequency, L is the inductance of the coil element, and C is the capacitance.

6 turns of copper tubing will likely not be anywhere near enough. I would plan on having a primary coil with at least 12 turns. You also need  to give yourself room to tune the coil.

You don't give enough specifications of your build so this is about as much help as I can give you at this point.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! Sorry about the lack of detail but I will try and fill you in as much as possible. I measured the resonant frequency with an oscilloscope and a function generator and got 5100 kHz. I am not sure if that is unreasonable or not because I measured that without the top load. I used 24 awg copper magnet wire on the secondary and unfortunately have not yet limited the MOT current (which I havent had a problem with yet). I definitely will take your advice with the primary coil and buy more tubing to get more turns. Thanks again for your help--Matt

Comment: The topload is absolutely critical to the resonant frequency as it is the main capacitive element in the secondary LC circuit. Any measurement you take without it is useless.

Comment: Ok. So aside from finding the new resonant frequency do you think I should consider building an mmc and current limiting the MOT? Thanks a lot! @DerStrom8

Comment: Yes, definitely limit your MOT current. This can usually be done by putting a third MOT in series with the two parallel primary windings of the other two MOTs, and shorting out the series MOT secondary. This will act as a ballast and limit MOT current. As for using a MMC, that would definitely be the ideal option.